# Adobe Phonegap build error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Adobe PhoneGap Build Error When a plugin - "file-transfer"

Log: [javac] /project/src/org/apache/cordova/filetransfer/FileTransfer.java:683: error: cannot find symbol

My config.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>City Sale</name>
    <description>
        City-Sale sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>      
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.1.1" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />      
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10" /> 
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.crosswalk.engine" source="pgb" />   
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/splash.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

If you remove it from the line: `<gap: plugin name = "org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />`
the **Adobe PhoneGap Build** compiles the application without error.

Comment: what is on line 683 in your FileTransfer.java file?

Comment: Your post is missing quite a few things. Based on your comment (cli-5.1.1) it seems you are using PhoneGap Build, so how does your _config.xml_ look and from which operating system build (iOS, Android or WP8) you get the error? Also when adding information to your question, use edit instead of comments.

Comment: what line did you add in config.xml to add the plugin? Plugin ids have changed in v5.x

Comment: @Quickfix, PGB has been moving the plugins quite a bit. The OP may need source=npm or source=plugins.cordova.io Otherwise, it might be a compile error and the OP should go to http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi

Comment: Hooray !!! Working! with source = plugins.cordova.io